# What is a right pattern for transmitting different changes to a Model to a Child Component?

Tags: observable, angular8, ng-zorro-antd

Hi I have a parent component that allows one to select different fields. I'm using nz-zorro's date selector and select components. For example, Date from a date selector, a couple of strings from drop down select fields etc. I've figured that you can use a a Subject event to emit changes to the child components input as and when any of the individual field selectors' callbacks are called.

It seems to me that making an event/input/output for each variable is a repetitive pattern that could be avoided by mapping all these fields I care about to one model.

My question then becomes how do I synchronize changes to any field of a model in one function or in a non code paste way....

```
var1DateEvent: Subject <Date> = new Subject <Date>();
var2StringEvent: Subject <string> = new Subject <string>();
```

Instead of having

```
onvar1Change(){ this.var1DateEvent.next(this.ngModelDate)}
onvar2Change(){ thos.var2StringEvent.next(this.ngModelString)}
```

Where the model variables are the models mapped to my UI components and onvar1Change() is the callback mapped to that UI element, the child component subscribes to these Input Observable inside its init file.

What I would like to do is have a custom model that has all these changeable fields and whenever any field of the model is changed, the UI emits an event of the entire model to the Child component. This feels like a better pattern to me but I'm not sure how to go about it as I'm new to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a parent child relation in your component there is no need to use the subject observable , i suggest you to use the @Input and @Output, for synchronising the changes in your child component

1. firstly in your parent component make a variable:

```
var1DateEvent:any;
```

2. In your html file where you're calling the child component paste this code on:

   ```
   <your-app-selector-name [var1DateEvent]="var1DateEvent" ></your-app-selector-name
   ```
3. In your child component place:

```
@Input() var1DateEvent;
```

and call the ngOnChanges() :

```
ngOnChanges(){
console.log('changes from parent component',var1DateEvent);
}
```

also you need to import Input from :
import { Component, OnInit ,Input } from '@angular/core';

I hope this would help you, Thanks

Comment: this worked, and is something fundamental i came across, the problem is that nz-zorro the component im using doesn't register changes to OnChange lifecycle hook

Comment: in nz-zorro you need to put  change detection event when you get selected date and then assign the changed value to  your variable you had created to store the date ,and then ngOnChange life cycle hook will detect change , it would clear me more if you show the code , Thanks fibonachoceres